# Shifting values between Data Grid View

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, sqlite

I have a problem. I create tabs in the newly created objects Data Grid (each has different information, which also calculate the average). The data in the Data Grid are written to the SQLite database. After reading the DGV creates a dynamic column from the arithmetic mean, I want to move without having to write to the database to another column. Is a good way would be to store data in an array?

Comment: What you are doing might be more clear If you share your code.. So we coud understand better than you are teling :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you just want to move the values to another datagridview, your are on the right track, you can store them in an array or a list. Afterwards, you can iterate the array and fill the column in the other dgv.
If i didn't understand correctly please edit your question and add more details.